# How can I calculate total user stories and tasks a developer completes in Rally?

Tags: rally

I am trying to do some analysis on team member contribution in Rally. The quantitative data will supplement the qualitative data about how much value a team member creates. Our teams work on user stories with story point estimates and each story has 1 or more tasks with hour estimates.

I'd like to take the hour estimates to determine what percentage of the user stories that each team member contributed and then total the fractions of story points for each developer each month.

Has anyone else solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You may start with a [code example here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-with-tasks) that builds a grid of stories and associated tasks that displays ScheduleState, PlanEstimate, TaskEstimateTotal, TaskRemainingTotal, Owner values for stories as well as State, Estimate, ToDo, and Owner values for associated tasks. The stories are filtered by iteration.

The grid is based on [Rally.data.custom.Store](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.custom.Store), which allows adding custom columns (that do not correspond to actual fields in Rally object model). Those columns can be populated by values derived from whatever calculation logic you code in your app. There is no built-in mechanism of deriving individual contributions in Rally.